# Sort Table after Append jQuery/ Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, append

Below is my code, when clicking add button to my table, my question is, are there ways to sort the table based on `ItemId` after `table.append`?

```
    var ItemList = "<tr><td hidden id='ItemIdEdit'>" +
    ItemId +
    "</td><td id='ItemCodeEdit'>" +
    ItemCode +
    "</td><td style='text-align: right'>" +

    parseFloat(Quantity).toFixed(2) +
    "</td><td id='ItemUOM2'>" +


    ItemUOM +
    "</td><td hidden>" +
    LocationId +
    "</td><td>" +
    LocationCode +
    "</td><td style='text-align: right'>" +
    UnitCostParse +
    "</td><td style='text-align: right' >" +

    Total2 +
    "</td><td><div class='buttons'> <a href='#' class='btn btn-default btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-edit' id='btnEdit'onclick='EditItem(this)'></div></td><td><div class='buttons'><a href='#' class='btn btn-default btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-trash' id='btnAddToList'onclick='RemoveItem(this)'></a></div></td></tr>";

tblItemList.append(ItemList);
```

Edit, please see below screenshot on what I want to achieve:
I want my table to be order by the highlighted column, are their any ways to sort the entire table after clicking add/edit?

[image]

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_sort_table Hi Everyone, thanks for your comments, I was able to solve this by adding sort function at the end of my append as per attached link.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the methods `append`, `prepend` and `after` to move the nodes.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/append

Pseudo code for vanilla javascript:

```
document.getElementById("yourTableIdOrTbody").append(document.getElementById("yourTrToMOveToTheEnd"));
document.getElementById("yourTableIdOrTbody").prepend(document.getElementById("yourTrToMOveToTheBegin"));
document.getElementById("trIdBase").after(document.getElementById("yourTrToMOveToAfterTrBase"));
```

For JQuery (https://api.jquery.com/after/):

```
$("#yourTableIdOrTbody").append($("#yourTrToMOveToTheEnd"));
$("#yourTableIdOrTbody").prepend($("#yourTrToMOveToTheBegin"));
$("#trIdBase").after($("#yourTrToMOveToAfterTrBase"));
```

Of course you don't need to have the id's to match the nodes. You can search the nodes using any other way.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, any idea on how my table will be sorted accordingly?

Comment: If your table is always sorted, for insert the first row, use `append` function over the `table` or `tbody`. For others, before insert next next line you can search for the last line node (`tr`) where itemId is less than your itemId, and you can use `after` function over that node

Answer (score 0):

Since you append to something called `tblItemList`, I assume you want to sort a data-structure and not actual elements.

```js
    let tblItemList = [];
    var ItemList = "<tr><td hidden id='ItemIdEdit'>" +
    2 +
    "</td><td id='ItemCodeEdit'>" +
    2 +
    "</td><td style='text-align: right'>" +

    parseFloat(2).toFixed(2) +
    "</td><td id='ItemUOM2'>" +


    2 +
    "</td><td hidden>" +
    2 +
    "</td><td>" +
    2 +
    "</td><td style='text-align: right'>" +
    2 +
    "</td><td style='text-align: right' >" +

    2 +
    "</td><td><div class='buttons'> <a href='#' class='btn btn-default btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-edit' id='btnEdit'onclick='EditItem(this)'></div></td><td><div class='buttons'><a href='#' class='btn btn-default btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-trash' id='btnAddToList'onclick='RemoveItem(this)'></a></div></td></tr>";

tblItemList.push(ItemList);
    ItemList = "<tr><td hidden id='ItemIdEdit'>" +
    1 +
    "</td><td id='ItemCodeEdit'>" +
    2 +
    "</td><td style='text-align: right'>" +

    parseFloat(2).toFixed(2) +
    "</td><td id='ItemUOM2'>" +


    2 +
    "</td><td hidden>" +
    2 +
    "</td><td>" +
    2 +
    "</td><td style='text-align: right'>" +
    2 +
    "</td><td style='text-align: right' >" +

    2 +
    "</td><td><div class='buttons'> <a href='#' class='btn btn-default btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-edit' id='btnEdit'onclick='EditItem(this)'></div></td><td><div class='buttons'><a href='#' class='btn btn-default btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-trash' id='btnAddToList'onclick='RemoveItem(this)'></a></div></td></tr>";

tblItemList.push(ItemList);
for (let i = 0; i < tblItemList.length; i++) {
    for (let j = i + 1; j < tblItemList.length; j++) {
        let itemI = parseInt($(tblItemList[i]).find("#ItemIdEdit").text());
        let itemJ = parseInt($(tblItemList[j]).find("#ItemIdEdit").text());
        if (itemI > itemJ) {
            let aux = tblItemList[i];
            tblItemList[i] = tblItemList[j];
            tblItemList[j] = aux;
        }
    }
}

console.log(tblItemList);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Note that you use the same `id` multiple times, which causes invalid HTML. The issue is solvable though, but you might want to fix that as well.

Comment: `.append()` is a DOM function, not an array function, so I'm not sure OP was trying to build a data structure, rather just trying sort some DOM elements. Also the DOM is already a mutable variable, trying to also maintain an array and keep it synchronized with the DOM is likely going to end up being quite the headache.

Comment: @PoorlyWrittenCode the fact that OP appends a text makes me think that it is a data structure that was not defined in the question.

Comment: @PoorlyWrittenCode but it's possible that you are right. If the op will tell me that this is actual DOM code, then I will remove my answer.

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery you can [detach](https://api.jquery.com/detach/#detach-selector), [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) and [append](https://api.jquery.com/append/) to reorder elements.

As mentioned in the other answers, giving elements identical IDs will cause problems, although you can easily fix this by using `class`es instead.

Here some sample code:

```js
$('button.add-item').on('click', function() {
  let item_id = (Math.random()+'').slice(-4);

  $('table').append(`
    <tr>
      <td class="item-id hidden">
        ${item_id}
      </td>
      <td class="item-code-edit">
        <input value="${item_id}" disabled>
      </td>
      <td class="item-cost align-right">
        ${parseFloat(Math.random() * 1000).toFixed(2)}
      </td>
      <td class="item-uofm">
        ItemUOM 
      </td>
      <td class="location-id hidden">
        LocationId
      </td>
      <td class="location-code">
        LocationCode
      </td>
      <td class="unit-cost-parse align-right">
        UnitCostParse
      </td>
      <td class="total align-right">
        Total2
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="buttons">
          <button class="edit-item btn btn-default btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-edit">EDIT</button>
          <button class="remove-item btn btn-default btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-trash">REMOVE</button>
        </div>
      </td>
   </tr>`);
   
   //this is the code that does the re-ordering
   $('table').append($('table').find('tr').detach().sort((a, b) =>
     $(a).find('.item-id').text() - $(b).find('.item-id').text()));
 });
 
 $('table')
   .on('click', 'button.edit-item', function() {
     let $id_input = $(this).parents('tr').find('.item-code-edit input');
     $id_input.prop('disabled', !$id_input.prop('disabled'));
   })
   .on('click', 'button.remove-item', function() {
     $(this).parents('tr').remove();
 });
```

```css
.align-right{
  text-align: right;}

.hidden{
  display: none;}
  
.item-code-edit input{
  width: 40px;}

table td{
  min-width: 64px;}
```

```html
<button class="add-item">ADD ITEM</button>
<table></table>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for this, I followed your code in the  re-ordering, however after click the button, the table is completely vanished (/detached). I'm checking further on how this works on my end

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your comments, I was able to solve this by adding a sort function at the end of my append as per the attached link.

Please find below the addition to my code, I called this function after my append.

```
function sortTable() {
        var table, rows, switching, i, x, y, shouldSwitch;
        table = document.getElementById("tblItemList");
        switching = true;
        /*Make a loop that will continue until
        no switching has been done:*/
        while (switching) {
            //start by saying: no switching is done:
            switching = false;
            rows = table.rows;
            /*Loop through all table rows (except the
            first, which contains table headers):*/
            for (i = 1; i < (rows.length - 1); i++) {
                //start by saying there should be no switching:
                shouldSwitch = false;
                /*Get the two elements you want to compare,
                one from current row and one from the next:*/
                x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[8];
                y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("TD")[8];

                var cmpX = isNaN(parseInt(x.innerHTML)) ? x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() : parseInt(x.innerHTML);
                var cmpY = isNaN(parseInt(y.innerHTML)) ? y.innerHTML.toLowerCase() : parseInt(y.innerHTML);
                cmpX = (cmpX == '-') ? 0 : cmpX;
                cmpY = (cmpY == '-') ? 0 : cmpY;
                //check if the two rows should switch place:
                if (cmpX > cmpY) {
                    //if so, mark as a switch and break the loop:
                    shouldSwitch = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (shouldSwitch) {
                /*If a switch has been marked, make the switch
                and mark that a switch has been done:*/
                rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i + 1], rows[i]);
                switching = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This function works, but should be improved. Never use loop variables outside (is bad practice). You should force the variable to be declared inside to avoid this error (`for (let i = 1; . . .`, than you can move the code of `if (shouldSwitch) {. . .}` to the place where `shouldSwitch = true;` (and remove the ìf` and the variable `shouldSwitch`). Also now, you can remove the `break`. Other situation is `rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[8]` shloud be `rows[i].children[8]`, because not work well if you have one table inside of this table